# Iterate over SimpleXMLElement array and print items to separate text files

Tags: php, arrays, pdf, foreach, docusignapi

So I'm having a rough time with possibly a simple problem. I have a SimpleXMLElement array of objects (PDF data bytes). I'm trying to iterate over my array and have the code write out each chunk of PDF 
data bytes to individual text files so I can write them to individual PDF files. My code is as follows:

```
$docfiles = $xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . "/" . $xml->EnvelopeStatus->DocumentStatuses->DocumentStatus->Name . '.txt';
$doctxt = fopen($docfiles,"w");
$docarr = array();
foreach($xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF as $post){
    foreach ($post->PDFBytes as $docusigntxt) {
        $docarr[] = $docusigntxt;
        foreach ($docarr as $value) {
            fwrite($doctxt,$value);
        }
    }
}
fclose($doctxt);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a case of getting to know how to properly drill down into the SimpleXML syntax. This is what solved my problem. I skipped over creating the text files and created PDFs, which is what I wanted:

```
foreach($xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF as $value) {
    $binary = base64_decode($value->PDFBytes);
    file_put_contents($xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . "/" . $value->Name, $binary);
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, it might be worth checking out the DocuSign SOAP API sample code that's available on GitHub:  https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK.  What you're trying to accomplish is pretty straight-forward -- I imagine the PHP folder in the GitHub repository would contain a code snippet that shows you how to achieve your goal.

Comment: We're using the REST API for our project and this is for our listener. I have looked through the code from GitHub and didn't find anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Using the REST API for your integration is great, but the listener application that you build to receive events from DocuSign Connect will either be implemented as an HTTPS listener or as a SOAP listener (i.e., REST API is not relevant to the listener). This GitHub sample provides an example of an HTTPS listener in PHP:  https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/tree/master/PHP/Connect.  That sample code should be a good starting point for implementing a listener app in PHP.

Comment: I'm already way past that. I've already got the listener taking the pushed XML response and downloading the XML file via HTTPS and parsing it. Where I'm stuck right now is looping through the SimpleXMLElement objects, "grabbing" the PDFBytes data and then write each one to its own text file and save it. Then I could create a PDF file from each text file, then delete the text files when that is done.

Comment: Okay, got it...thanks for the clarification.  So, the question is really just how to (in PHP) take a base64-encoded byte stream (i.e., contents of PDFBytes element) and write it to a PDF file.  I'm not very familiar with PHP, but perhaps the answer to this other post would help you achieve your goal:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004809/recreate-pdf-file-from-java-to-php.  (Relevant part of the post being the PHP code that creates the PDF file from the base64-encoded string.)

Comment: The problem is that the XML document contains at the very least two PDF documents (usually more). I can get it to write to a text file (all the PDFBytes for that Envelope appear in the one text file, which is not what I want) and I can get it to write a PDF file (the first PDFBytes object, but none of the others). It's getting each SimpleXMLElement object (which contains the PDFBytes data) to write to its own file that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: I'm stuck at it only looping once and printing out the first PDF data byte. Does anyone have any advice? This is driving me insane!