# Is there a way to recreate a PDF from a stream in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, stream

I am trying to recreate a pdf from pdf streams that gets output from an api. 
Firstly on the return the header seem to be missing and in firebug I get many errors about XRef (table) stream headers being invalid.
I decided that I could simply test by opening a pdf in a text editor and save a txt file and then read from it. From that try to be able to recreate the pdf.
Also if I then went and opened the text file and save back to a pdf it will not work anymore.

I am new to this and this is my first attempt at it naively believing that it would not be very hard.

Is it possible to take output streams of pdf and recreate back to a pdf file? If so how would I go about doing so?

I do not know very much about it and have tried to look up a few things but have not got very far.

I put a comment but think it would be better here.

so a stream is as such:

```
`4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 890>>
stream
xœ½V]S1½û´ÿÁñ>êŒ¦ùØd³ Uèà*t†Ç(¥¢ÛVÛ">øã=Iw—–"ÌÈdòu“Üœ{öô¦ü“%Ÿ³RJè\²u^ä^ó°±d^ŠÌ.1Ê„TWYêSåŠŸ’ù€Gœâ¡œ]j'ƒôòv“k‘gŠŸz/Œ*xÒçþ”~Jyff´0Æ/ÀTE&l^,€ZµÔ§Ê?‹0“/µ0ëí
Lmr‘Ûœ¬ùM*…u9Ÿ§¯ºÜÚÖì„Ï-wOx«›*!¥ä¶„¾“¶:ûŠÓæˆäî$ýü±7kuÿ¨µ°8ŠQqX#s…Ú;î
¹µ£ys4—Ô}…KKát
,¡1V§—ÃÝcæG´I‡4CeÚ£>õhL:~ÌÝo8¿pÛQ_Z‚wçýµëB›UoÑoúJ§t„:Ãõ»tFCÌú
<ü‰Ùÿ4úžm™^÷ý,VëöŠßÔåþ/E
endstream
endobj`
```

I have tried to decode it using below: note the code above is a snippit of the whole file

```
$pdf_base64 = "assets/evidential-3.txt";
$pdf_base64_handler = fopen($pdf_base64,'r');
$pdf_content = fread ($pdf_base64_handler,filesize($pdf_base64));
$pdf_new = gzdeflate($pdf_content, 890);
$pdf = gzinflate($pdf_new);
var_dump($pdf_content); exit;
```

As you can see by the names of the varliables i have tried to base64 the code. The api will do something like this:

```
//set response type
inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/pd4mltest.pdf");
//input stream gets the pdf
inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/pd4mltest.pdf");
outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
//set output stream to response
OUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

I have also tried what has been done in another solution in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004809/recreate-pdf-file-from-java-to-php)
where I added:

```
$stringWithFile = "assets/evidential-3.txt";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=document.pdf');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
flush();
file_put_contents("document.pdf", base64_decode($stringWithFile));
readfile("document.pdf");
exit();
```

But I get these sort of errors:

```
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
Error: Invalid XRef stream header
pdf.worker.js (line 249)
<System>

XRef_readXRef@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3613:13
XRef_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:3207:23
PDFDocument_setup@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2449:7
PDFDocument_parse@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2329:7
LocalPdfManager_ensure/<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1901:20
LocalPdfManager_ensure@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1896:1
BasePdfManager_ensureDoc@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1832:14
loadDocument/</<@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:38456:11

pdf.worker.js (line 251)
<System>
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
pdf.worker.js (line 234)
<System>
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects
pdf.worker.js (line 234)
<System>
An error occurred while loading the PDF. PDF.js v1.0.473 (build: 1694cd8) Message: InvalidPDFException
```

Comment: what exactly is a "pdf stream"? PDF isn't a "streamable" format, like video/audio.

Comment: It helps if you show what you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I made a stupid mistake but is fixed. When returned all I needed to do was:

```
$stringWithFile = $resultjson;
header('Content-Type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=document.pdf');     

file_put_contents("document.pdf", $stringWithFile);

readfile('document.pdf');

exit();
```